# PASCAL: converting user input string to first letter uppercase, the rest lowercase. How can I do this?

Tags: pascal, uppercase, lowercase

As it says in the title.

I'm writing a program which asks the user to input a surname surname then a first name and finally an address.

When this is done it prints out a table of the results and then organises then alphabetically based first on surname, then first name and finally address.

All this is done. I just have to make it that the table always prints out with first letters uppercase and the rest lowercase, ie:

input: jOHN SMith
output: John Smith

How can I do this in Pascal?

Here is the code I've written for this part so far:

```
writeln();
write(UpCaseFirstChar(arrSurnames[count]):15);
write(UpCaseFirstChar(arrFirstNames[count]):15);
write(UpCaseFirstChar(arrAddress[count]):30);
writeln();
```

I have a function for uppercasing the first letter, how can I change it to lowercase the rest?

EDIT: Here is the uppercase function:

```
function UpCaseFirstChar(const S: string): string;
begin
 Result := S;

 if Length(Result) > 0 then
 Result[1] := UpCase(Result[1]);
end;
```

EDIT 2: I think I figured it out. Here is the new code for the UpCase/LowerCase function in case anyone is interested:

```
function UpCaseFirstChar(const S: string): string;
var
   i: integer;
begin
   Result := S;

   if Length(Result) > 0 then
   Result[1] := UpCase(Result[1]);
   for i := 2 to Length(Result) do
      begin
         Result[i] := LowerCase(Result[i]);
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show your `UpCaseFirstChar` funciton. Why don't you look up the Pascal string function that converts to all lower case. Use that first, then upcase the first letter.

Comment: Good idea. Sorry I never showed it to begin with. I've updated the OP. Could I use the lowercase function INSIDE the upcase function?

Comment: Of course you can call the lower case function inside your `UpCaseFirstChar` function and do everything you need in that one function. By the way, why do you assign `Result := S` first? You should operate on `S`, then do your result assignment last, in my opinion. Your argument is passed by value, so you aren't going to end up changing the string the caller passes directly by changing `S`.

Comment: Although what you added will work, there's a cleaner solution (see my posted answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update is more verbose than it needs to be. If you read the documentation carefully, the function `LowerCase` applies to a *string*. So you could write:

```
function UpCaseFirstChar(const S: string): string;
begin
  if Length(S) = 0 then
    Result := S
  else begin
    Result := LowerCase(S);
    Result[1] := UpCase(Result[1]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, you're absolutely right. I wasn't paying good enough attention and when it appeared to do what I wanted, I just accepted it. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that this (and the OP's implementation) won't work with many surnames such as *McDonald*, *MacDonald*, *O'Malley*, *de Leon*. (Upvoted your answer, BTW. Just a note for future readers.)

Comment: @KenWhite indeed. I was taking the question at total face value, which was how to make the first letter upper case, and make the rest lower case. My answer definitely would have been different if the question were, "How do I write a function to properly capitalize a surname" (which is a much more difficult problem. :)

Comment: Indeed. I have code that works for most common surnames (like the *Mac*, *Mc*, and *O'Malley* in my last comment; it wouldn't properly handle *de *, but fortunately that's not a common issue where I live. :-)